# .NET Core Razor Pages using AJAX Get to populate the data inside of a bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, razor-pages

I am facing an issue using AJAX GET to put data from database in a modal. The database code is all working however when I try to do a GET using Ajax, the ID that i'm using to fetch data from the database is always 0 when passed to the handler.
[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbXhw.png)
Here we can see that the value associated with the card is a unique ID given to each shift

[AJAX Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DBRB.png)
Here I am attempting to pass this value through the AJAX post, when I do a JS Alert, the value is there and is displayed, however when the function is called and the data is passed, it is given the value of zero. I've tried many different ways to get this to work to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!
[C# Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY6rX.png)

[Modal Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7u8A.png)

Comment: can you post your model class' code?

Comment: @vhr I have edited the post with a link to the modal code! Note: The modal does appear as expected, however the contents inside say "undefined"

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model doesn't know how to bind the id param. this should work:

```
data: {
   id: shiftId
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The value is being passed now!